# i want to make data as image type in rdlc reports(pdf)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I want to make data as image  rather than text so the user can't copy the text from pdf in rdlc reports.

```
 public FileResult DownloadArticle(int id)
    {
        SignalRDataContext srcontext = new SignalRDataContext();
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
        localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report/Report1.rdlc");
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        localReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
        reportDataSource.Value = srcontext.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleID == id).Select(x => new { x.code, x.Article_Name }).ToList();
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        string reportType = "pdf";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension = "pdf";
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;
        renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Membership." + fileNameExtension);
        return File(renderedBytes, fileNameExtension);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the report type and extension to TIFF. [SQL Server Reporting Services supports reports using the TIFF format](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159216%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
public FileResult DownloadArticle(int id)
{
    ...
    string reportType = "tiff";
    ...
    string fileNameExtension = "tiff";
    ...
}
```